# Exstract Value from Gridview Cell created by function in Item Templates

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble retrieving the value of a cell in a gridview.

I think it may have something to do with the item template calling a function since I am able to retrieve the values of cells that are not calling a function in the same gridview.

How can i extract the displayed value from this cell?

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
         lblTest.Text=row.Cells[7].Text; 

}
```

```
 <ItemTemplate>

    <%# GetWednesday(decimal.Parse(Eval("Wed").ToString())).ToString("N2") %>

 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Poking around a little more, it appears your content is there, but not as text. It is a `DataBoundLiteralControl` in the cell's `Controls` collection. You can get the value with:

```
var value = (row.Cells[7].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text.Trim();
```

Use of the `Trim()` function is necessary to remove leading and trailing whitespace above and below the binding statement in your template.

I still prefer the approach described below.

**End**

<strike>If I understand correctly, I think your value is not stored in ViewState.</strike>

You can get at your text with this alternate approach:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="mylabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# GetWednesday(decimal.Parse(Eval("Wed").ToString())).ToString("N2") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

And from code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var label = GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("mylabel") as Label;
     lblTest.Text = label.Text; 
}
```